# Can you connect PHP Yii framework with parse.com?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, parse-platform

I'm at the beginning designing a social game both for web and mobile. I get a lot of encouragement to start developing my database/backend on parse considering the big support and popularity (community) it has for me as a beginner.
 While I have no doubt I can migrate my current MySQL database onto parse, I am wondering if there's a way to connect my existing Yii front-end to use the cloud instead of mysql?

I tried googling and looking up extensions but Parse being both a name and a common verb makes it hard to search and I did not find any relevant topics out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is extension in yii framework known yiiparsedb .please refer following link

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiparsedb/

Answer (score 0):

Just specify different logins than `localhost` (since i don't use parse.com, i don't know login string):

```
'components' => [
  'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=parse.com/ajshgdj-ad;port=3306;dbname=mydb',
  'username' => 'parse_user',
  'password' => 'q7we89a4s56d',
]
```

When googling, specify `parse.com` keyword

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the keyword search, things became much clearer once used like that. Regarding the connection I found some packages and API's that integrate with parse.com's REST API for exchange and operations.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of using the proper keywords I found the 3rd party libraries to connect most platforms and frameworks with parse.com.

Looks like the Yii PHP Api is out for over two years now. Anyone looking for the same answer can find the libraries at this link here:

[Yii PHP API library for parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries)